# Dual monitors on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors

Dual monitor set up with monitor 1 on the right.

It's a dual boot system with Win10 - monitors work fine under windows so not hardware.

When I configure and click apply, right hand screen becomes screen 2 and left hand screen goes completely blank i.e. like the monitor has gone to sleep.

starting gnome from terminal:
[image: terminal error message]

And yet when I screenshotted it I see the attached.

Graphics card is GeForce 7600GT. Driver is X.Org X Server Nouveau driver

Is there some low level config I can access directly from terminal?

[image: screenshot]

Thanks